# Mount sql dump inside a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my docker-compose file i have created a database service. There i have my local (outside) folder named ´database´ under volumes. I have copied my sql file (`sql.sql`) into this folder. But when I go into the database container, I don't see it. what did I do wrong?

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:

  database:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=me
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - ./database:/home
```

Folder structure

```
/database
    sql.sql
/docker-compose.yaml
```

Comment: Can you use the `mysql` command-line tool from the host to load that file into the database, without necessarily doing anything Docker-specific?  If `mysql -h127.0.0.1 ... < sql.sql` works, you don't need this `volumes:` mount.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank for your comment! Maybe is that a good workaround but my question is why my volume dont show the files which i mounted. Do you have an idea?